# Url encoding for non-ASCII characters

Tags: url, urlencode

I understand why we should url-encode reserved characters is some cases.
For example, if we write this: `http://example.com/somepage?searchText=abc&maxResults=10`

The URL above transmits two pieces of information to the server:

> searchText=abc
>
> maxResults=10

It is because we have reserved characters in the url:

[image]

But if we want to convey the searchText ​​​​​​​content with the value of:

> searchText=**abc&maxResults=10**

We need to use url-encoding

```
http://example.com/somepage?searchText=abc%26maxResults%3D10
```

[image]

But I don't understand why any character outside the ASCII charset should be url-encoded? (For example - cyrillic symbols such a "у П х з", or chinese etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems I find the answer:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.1

For original character sequences that contain non-ASCII characters,
however, the situation is more difficult. Internet protocols that
transmit octet sequences intended to represent character sequences
are expected to provide some way of identifying the charset used, if
there might be more than one [RFC2277].  However, there is currently
no provision within the generic URI syntax to accomplish this
identification. An individual URI scheme may require a single
charset, define a default charset, or provide a way to indicate the
charset used.